# Get id from selected item listbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms

With a `SELECT` query I get some data from the database (for example users). I put all the data in a `List<User>`.

```
List<User> listUsers = new List<User>();
```

To load this data in the listbox I do:

```
Foreach(User u in listUsers)
{
     listbox.Items.Add(u.name + " " + u.lastname)
}
```

What I would like to do is the next:

When someone clicks on one of the list items (on one of the users), my c# form application need to get the user id (from the dbs) from the selected user.

```
string name = listbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

I can't do:

```
SELECT UserID FROM Person WHERE Username = name;
```

Because the `SelectedItem` will contain a name and last name with a space.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you introduce a Property `ID` in your `User` class? You could fill that property too along with other data. Then you can also override the `ToString()` method in your class user which will help you to display the name and lastname. You can add instances of `User` class instead of strings and cast selections directly to the `User` class where you have your `ID`. Check the code:

```
public class User
{
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public override string ToString()
       {
             return Name + " " + LastName;
       }
       ...
}

//fill the listBox
foreach(User u in listUsers)
{
       listbox.Items.Add(u);
}

//get the celected User

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
       User user = (User)lb.Items[lb.SelectedIndex];
       MessageBox.Show(user.ID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You are so awesome! Thanks! :)... But it returns 0. #Edit

Comment: You should set the ID of each User instance when you read it from the database. For insntance use `SELECT UserID, Username, Lastname FROM Person;` when you read the users.

Comment: Well, if you don't set the ID of each user, the ID Property will be initialized to 0. If that happens for all users, than you are not setting it in the first place.

Comment: I am getting the ID from the database.. :(

Comment: Then you shouldn't be having a problem at all. I tested this code. Could you please post your current code?

Comment: Posted it! User was just an example, this is the real one. (blog)

Comment: Hmm I got a problem I think :P Yesterday it worked perfectly, but today I get this errror: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'BlogOMatic.Klassen.Blog'.

Comment: Nvm It worked! I used u.Tostring() instead of only u in the foreach loop! TY

Comment: Hmm can u maybe explain me why we do this: Listbox lb = (ListBox)sender. What does it do? especially the Sender?

Comment: The sender is the control that triggered the event, because it is object, you should cast it to its real type. In this case, you can use listbox variable instead

Answer (score 0):

While filling the listbox, make a query to get the UserID column along with user name, user last name.

Create a class that will represent each item of the list, such as

```
public class UserInfo
{
   public string DisplayName {get; set;}
   public int UserID {get; set;}
}
```

Make `listUsers` to be of `List<UserInfo>` type. While filling the data from the tables into the list, do the following

```
while (myUserData.Read())
{
   listUsers.Add(new UserInfo() {DisplayName = myUserData["DisplayName"] , UserID = myUserData["UserID")})
}
```

Post the list filling, use `DataSource` to bind the data, `DisplayMember` property to the DisplayName property, `ValueMember` property to UserID property.

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) page for an example of how to use databinding for details.